# WebServiceException thrown from the java application

Tags: java, web-services, exception, soap, wsdl

I have created an application which uses web service to login, register, add and edit a customer. When I run the application after deploying the webservice, it throws a exception named webServiceException in the application's console.
This is what it shows:

```
 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Method editCustomer is exposed as WebMethod, but there is no corresponding wsdl operation with name {http://Client_server_CW_WS/}editCustomer in the wsdl:portType{http://Client_server_CW_WS/}CW_WS
```

Can I know how to solve this as there is a corresponding wsdl operation written for this in my code?
I used glassfish server for this

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the netbeans IDE try Clean and build.